# How does one assert a single field in error type?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

Let's assume I have code such as this:

```scala
final case class CustomException(errorCode: Int, id: UUID) extends Throwable

val logic: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Unit] = ???
```

I would like to use ZIO Test to check for a specific error case

```scala
val checkForTimeout = testM("Logic should time out") {
  for {
    result <- logic.flip
  } yield assert(result, isSubtype[CustomException](???))
}
```

What I would like to do is check the `errorCode` field for a specific value. But it seems the existing combinators in ZIO Test only allow me to check the the full object.
I would like to only check for `_.errorCode` while ignoring `_.id`, which means `equalTo` is not a good enough combinator for this use case.

How would I go about addressing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Assertion.hasField`, which lets you "zoom in" on one part of a larger structure, to do this.

```scala
val checkForTimeout = testM("Logic should time out") {
  for {
    result <- logic.flip
  } yield assert(
      result,
      isSubtype[CustomException](hasField("errorCode", _.errorCode, equalTo(1)))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be to adjust the signature of `logic`.

```
val logic: ZIO[Any, CustomException, Unit] = ???
```

Now you can do something like:

```
val checkForTimeout = testM("Logic should time out") {
    for {
      result: CustomException <- logic.flip
    } yield assert(result.errorCode, equalTo(543))
}
```

If not you can still cast the result:

```
val checkForTimeout = testM("Logic should time out") {
    for {
      th <- logic.flip
      result = th.asInstanceOf[CustomException]
    } yield assert(result.errorCode, equalTo(543))
}
```

Comment: This would indeed work. But I cannot change the signature of `logic` and would like to avoid the cast. Adam's answer involving `hasField` is what I had hoped to find.